# Get operation_Id/operation_ParentId in inbound section of APIM policy

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, distributed-tracing

I setup an Azure API Management service with *Correlation protocol* set to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/). It uses the header `traceparent` for context propagation. If the API client sets `traceparent` header, the APIM service maps its content to the Azure Application Insights attributes `operation_Id` and `operation_ParentId`.

If the the `traceparent` header isn't set by the client, both attributes are generated by the service and provided via `context.Request.Headers` after the *backend* processing, which means also after the *inbound* processing. As a result, all `<send-request>` calls of the *inbound* section (e.g. authentication/validation logic) aren't able to propagate the tracing context correctly via the `traceparent` header.

**Is there any support for accessing generated tracing context in the *inbound* section of an APIM policy?**

1. As workaround I tried to set the `traceparent` header with manually generated values, but it's not considered/used by the service (e.g. for `<trace>` or *backend* calls).
2. I checked `RequestId` from the [Context variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables), but it contains a different value than `operation_id`.

**Alternatively, it there a solution to aggregate all telemetry data with same trace context?**

Comment: Found the same open question in the Microsoft Q&A, see [APIM expose W3C tracing trace-id parent-id for get/set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/553477/apim-expose-w3c-tracing-trace-id-parent-id-for-get).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround using the `Request Id` as custom `trace-id` values  in addition with a complex Kusto query.

1. If no `traceparent` is provided by the API client, set a custom header following [Get traceparent generated by APIM and return from response header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69971301/846163).

   ```xml
   <set-header name="traceparent" exists-action="skip">
     <value>@($"00-{context.RequestId.ToString("N")}-0000000000000000-01")</value>
   </set-header>
   ```
2. Extend the Kusto query according to the custom `trace-id`/`operation_Id`.

   ```
   let operationId="<APIM operation_Id value>";
   let customOperationIds=toscalar(requests
   | where operation_Id  == operationId
   | where customDimensions['Service Type'] == 'API Management'
   | extend customOperationId=replace_string(tostring(customDimensions['Request Id']), '-', '')
   | where customOperationId != operation_Id
   | summarize requestId=make_set(customOperationId, 1000));
   union *
   | where operation_Id in (operationId, customOperationIds)
   | order by timestamp asc
   ```